# Batch or Bash to remove a timestamp in thousands of files

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, batch-file, filenames

I made a major mistake today in handling my selfhosted backup system and wound up deleting about half of my user folder. Luckily, the backup existed and was able to copy all of my data over. The bad part is each file that was restored has a timestamp in the filename.

So a file that was filename.file is now filename~20170401-1999.file

I'm not too bright when it comes to batch files or what not, but is there any way a BAT could be programmed to run through every single filename and take out the timestamp? Every single timestamp starts with the ~ and ends with the period of the filetype. So removing everything including and after the tilde and stopping at the character before the period would fix the problem.

There are some 4600 files needing fixed with a wide variety of filetype extensions. I am on Windows 10 Pro and able to user powershell or bash to fix the error. I have the Windows Linux Subsystem installed, so a bash script is also acceptable.

Comment: Does there appear always exactly one `~` in each file name?

Comment: Already have an answer, but yes it appeared exactly once in every file that was restored from backup. Non restored files were simply filename.type while the restore ones were filename~dategroup-timegroup.type (I.E. resume~20170409-173314.pdf

Comment: Could have easily done this with any freely available file rename utility on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell offers a simple solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *~* | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '~[^.]+' } -WhatIf
```

- `-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operations; remove it, once you've confirmed that the command will work as intended.
- For simplicity I've made the assumption that any filename containing `~` must be renamed; the matching can be refined, if false positives must be eliminated:
  `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File *~[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*`
- Matching is limited to *files* (`-File`), located anywhere in the current directory's *subtree* (`-Recurse`).
  To only match files located *directly* in the current directory, remove `-Recurse`.
- The script block (`{ ... }`) passed to the `Rename-Item` cmdlet's `-NewName` parameter calculates the new filename:

  - `$_.Name` returns the input file's name (`$_` is PowerShell's automatic variable for representing the input object at hand).
  - `-replace '~[^.]+'` performs a regex-based string replacement: `'~[^.]+'` matches a `~` followed by any nonempty sequence (`+`) of characters other than `.` (`[^.]`).; not specifying a replacement string implicitly uses the empty string, so that the matching part is effectively removed from the name.

Answer (score 0):

Just some idea from the top of my head.

You can iterate over the files, and for each filename, you can replace the sub-string that match the regex `/~\d+-\d+/` with `""` (i.e., empty string) and use the modified string as the file's new name.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=~" %%p IN ("%%~na") DO (
  IF "%%q" neq "" ECHO(REN "%%a" "%%~p%%~xa"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Perform a directory scan with subdirectories in basic form withot directornames and assign to `%%a`. Then tokenise the name part of the full name found into `%%p` and `%%q` using `~` as a delimiter. If the second token is not empty then we have a timestamp in `%%q` so form the new filename from the part in `%%p` and the extension from `%%a`

Answer (score 0):

variation  of mklement0 without regex

```
 Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *~*.file | 
     rename-item -NewName {"{0}{1}" -f ($_.BaseName -split "~")[0], $_.Extension  } -WhatIf
```

a short version:

```
 gci -Rec -File -Filter *~*.file | ren -n {"{0}{1}" -f ($_.Base -split "~")[0], $_.Extension  } -WhatIf
```